# Custom File Type Icon Using InstallShield LE

Tags: icons, file-association, installshield-le

I recently had to convert my installer project when I upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012 because .vdproj files aren't supported. I went with InstallShield LE, and I think everything's working okay, but I don't know how to set the icon on a custom file type. I can set the icon on the application shortcuts, but not on the file type I've associated with the application. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I imported the .vdproj file, it copied over an incorrect directory for the icon file. I found this out when I was trying to rebuild the installer project, and the build failed because the icon file was missing. I don't quite understand what's going on, but I changed an entry in the .isl file to point to the location of the icon file:

```
<table name="Icon">
  <row><td>_F8BD094F_6318_4354_8857_12B610250F29</td><td/><td>C:\Updated\path\to\icon\file\myicon.ico</td><td>0</td></row>
</table>
```

This entry is referenced later in the file here:

```
<table name="ProgId">
  <col key="yes" def="s255">ProgId</col>
  <col def="S255">ProgId_Parent</col>
  <col def="S38">Class_</col>
  <col def="L255">Description</col>
  <col def="S72">Icon_</col>
  <col def="I2">IconIndex</col>
  <col def="I4">ISAttributes</col>
  <row><td>MedLnx Project</td><td/><td/><td>MedLnx Project File</td><td>_F8BD094F_6318_4354_8857_12B610250F29</td><td>0</td><td/></row>
</table>
```

However, now I am concerned about pointing to a static path. I'll run into the same situation on the target machine for another user if I don't have a relative path to the file. The icon file is in the project folder of the application to install (not the installer's project folder). I could move a copy there if it matters, but how does one get the relative path?

Comment: Nevermind, I just tested it out by moving the icon file to another directory and running the installer. It appears to be working fine, so I guess the icon gets packaged with the installer when it's built.